# Getting crash while going back in Navigation Stack, Not getting much out of back trace

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I am getting crash while getting back from navigation stack. Basically, I was trying to migrate from NavigationView to NavigationStack.

below is the stack trace, some how not getting any hint why it's happening.

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1b96d6ef8)
frame #0: 0x00000001b96d6ef8 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol194523 + 476
frame #1: 0x00000001b92a4c80 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol163702 + 176
frame #2: 0x00000001b905cd00 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol143411 + 7680
frame #3: 0x00000001b9058a00 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol143387 + 3840
frame #4: 0x00000001b9057794 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol143385 + 428
frame #5: 0x00000001b906bc04 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol143652 + 24
frame #6: 0x00000001b857f288 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol63520 + 28
frame #7: 0x00000001b8e2be18 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol128084 + 572
frame #8: 0x00000001b84aa6e0 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol59254 + 116
frame #9: 0x00000001b9057544 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol143383 + 572
frame #10: 0x00000001b93b5b30 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol169980 + 1644
frame #11: 0x00000001b93b5bf4 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol169981 + 72
frame #12: 0x00000001b6e1b274 UIKitCore`-[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 1564
frame #13: 0x00000001b6ecd22c UIKitCore`__49-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]_block_invoke + 208
frame #14: 0x00000001b6f8185c UIKitCore`-[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 116
frame #15: 0x00000001b74cce98 UIKitCore`__53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke_5 + 608
frame #16: 0x00000001b7cef1b0 UIKitCore`__UIVIEW_IS_EXECUTING_ANIMATION_COMPLETION_BLOCK__ + 36
frame #17: 0x00000001b6d9c114 UIKitCore`-[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 636
frame #18: 0x00000001b6d9b070 UIKitCore`-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 436
frame #19: 0x00000001b6d9a790 UIKitCore`-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 196
frame #20: 0x00000001b6d9a8a4 UIKitCore`-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 472
frame #21: 0x00000001b61b4ae8 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 232
frame #22: 0x0000000105bb604c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 20
frame #23: 0x0000000105bc6800 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1196
frame #24: 0x0000000105bc6344 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
frame #25: 0x00000001b4bd6a08 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
frame #26: 0x00000001b4bb8368 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2036
frame #27: 0x00000001b4bbd1e4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
frame #28: 0x00000001ed9dd368 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 164
frame #29: 0x00000001b706cd88 UIKitCore`-[UIApplication _run] + 888
frame #30: 0x00000001b706c9ec UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 340
frame #31: 0x0000000104b1fd30 MrDoc`main at AppDelegate.swift:15:7
frame #32: 0x00000001d2ee1948 dyld`start + 2504
```

Answer (score 0):

After wasting my 2 hours, I finally got the solution so basically this crash is related to state of navigation stack. I was not providing path argument in navigation stack. It's kind of strange that it is pushing the view without it but when we pop it, the state of navigation gets corrupted and get the crash. I wish Apple team works more towards better error diagnostics for SwiftUI. Might be helpful for someone who stumble upon this error.

```
NavigationStack(path: $navigationCoordinator.path) { // <= missing argument
                    HStack(spacing: 30.0) {
                        ForEach(categories) { item in
                            Button(action: {
                                navigationCoordinator.path.append(item)
                            }) {
                                GeometryReader { geometry in
                                    CategoryView(title: item.title,
                                                 image: item.image,
                                                 color: item.color,
                                                 shadowColor: item.shadowColor)
                                    .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(geometry.frame(in: .global).minX - 30) / -40),
                                                      axis: (x: 0, y: 10.0, z: 0))
                                }
                                .frame(width: 240, height: 320)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(for: Category.self, destination: { item in
                        IndexView()
                            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                    })
```